# How to run the local images/containers in docker?

Tags: linux, docker

Due to the lack of storage, I removed `/var/lib/` to the external hard disk `data`, which has caused a system crash.

After I reinstall the system I'd like to use the docker images I created before, so soft link firstly:

`ln -s /data/var/lib/docker/ /var/lib/docker`
`ln -s /data/var/lib/docker-engine/ /var/lib/docker-engine`

6 Files in `var/lib/docker/containers`:

```
6c60fb4b198ab1400358c56c08d3ec5886ef7266c5e904db259e56bf94cfdc39  b9194213bb77aa8d50e5f794c3b658fb18ca60ad2c6aae9fc2c79c832f4a23e8
856907304c45db8c951d44b9445e4c553d644b1f43c1df10096c7523ea848560  bd001fe7304b8c8558122673acde506874672fa2edd929e7824e3d81fdecf4d6
89b40c05fa839333d0d40927bdc1ab6c7b42496e8130aaded980a4dc02cb33e7  e7048fbb76e3a4857a90773346783d58b66aca74df0e77ededfe100f041b2067
```

Files in `var/lib/docker/image`:

```
myname:/var/lib/docker$ cd image/
myname:/var/lib/docker/image$ ls
overlay2
myname:/var/lib/docker/image$ cd overlay2/
myname:/var/lib/docker/image/overlay2$ ls
distribution  imagedb  layerdb  repositories.json
```

I've reinstalled docker and now,

`docker images` shows:

```
REPOSITORY              TAG                            IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
wav2letter              latest                         8f2bc1be8a04        3 months ago        8.94GB
<none>                  <none>                         8f076799dfcf        3 months ago        5.84GB
wav2letter/wav2letter   cuda-latest                    b43dac170ffe        3 months ago        8.94GB
ubuntu                  16.04                          9361ce633ff1        3 months ago        118MB
nvidia/cuda             9.2-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu16.04   78f3ecf29e62        4 months ago        3.02GB
nvidia/cuda             10.1-base                      39556dc8d077        4 months ago        129MB
nvidia/cuda             9.2-base                       86d52012c522        4 months ago        106MB
hello-world             latest                         fce289e99eb9        6 months ago        1.84kB
pytorch/pytorch         1.0-cuda10.0-cudnn7-devel      fa5b91571a44        7 months ago        5.45GB
```

and `docker ps -a` shows:

```
zd@user-System-Product-Name:~$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                        PORTS               NAMES
7f6aa3cd0163        hello-world                         "/hello"            25 minutes ago      Exited (0) 25 minutes ago                         ecstatic_sinoussi
a94e9c44df7e        hello-world                         "/hello"            27 minutes ago      Exited (0) 26 minutes ago                         dreamy_neumann
6c60fb4b198a        ubuntu:16.04                        "/bin/bash"         3 months ago        Exited (127) 3 months ago                         silly_visvesvaraya
856907304c45        wav2letter/wav2letter:cuda-latest   "/bin/bash"         3 months ago        Exited (255) 29 minutes ago                       tmpw2l
e7048fbb76e3        wav2letter/wav2letter:cuda-latest   "/bin/bash"         3 months ago        Exited (255) 29 minutes ago                       w2l-cxz
bd001fe7304b        wav2letter/wav2letter:cuda-latest   "/bin/bash"         3 months ago        Exited (255) 29 minutes ago                       w2l
b9194213bb77        wav2letter:latest                   "/bin/bash"         3 months ago        Exited (255) 29 minutes ago                       testdocker
89b40c05fa83        wav2letter:latest                   "/bin/bash"         3 months ago        Exited (255) 29 minutes ago                       myw2l
```

So how to `run` from the existed containers and images? thx.

Comment: How did you run your containers before? Why don't you rebuild your images or pull them from a registry? What does `docker image ls` print?

Comment: I used `docker run --runtime=nvidia -itd --name xxx1(name) xxx2:cuda-latest(src image)` and `docker exec -it xxx1 /bin/bash`. Don't know how to rebuild the images, and maybe it's exactly what I'm querying. `docker image ls` shows nothing.

Comment: If you used `docker commit` and managed to crash the Docker daemon and corrupt its local state, those images are gone.  If you used `docker build` (or `docker load`), just repeat the command you used.  If you never used either command, there's nothing to recover, just repeat your `docker run` commands.